# Update multiple tables in one query, in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I want update my tables from csv. Now data from csv are imported to table "temp_update_stany", but i cant update tables. Query with no errors, but nothing is updated.

Table from CSV is:

```
produkt|quantity|price|active|czas
```

Query:

```
UPDATE lp2_product tabela 
        INNER JOIN lp2_stock_available stany ON (tabela.id_product = stany.id_product)
        INNER JOIN lp2_product_lang lang ON (tabela.id_product = lang.id_product)
        INNER JOIN temp_update_stany csv ON (tabela.id_product = csv.produkt)
    SET
        tabela.active = csv.active,
        tabela.price = csv.price,
        lang.available_now = csv.czas,
        stany.quantity = csv.quantity
    WHERE
        csv.produkt = tabela.id_product 
        OR csv.produkt = lang.id_product 
        OR csv.produkt = stany.id_product
```

and output from query:

```
Modified records: 0 (Perform queries took 0.0322 seconds (s)).
```

but for example "lp2_product" /row 'active' have value 0 for all products and temp_update_stany have value 1 for all.

Yes, this is prestashop and simple script for update quantity and prices.

Comment: create a complete, verifiable example of this, and I bet you'll see the error right away.

Comment: BTW: You can completely delete your WHERE clause, because the first condition is allways true (redundant to JOIN ON clause) and the other two do not matter.

Comment: What you mean? I don't have errors, but this not update anything.

Comment: Without "WHERE" the same - no errors, no update.

Comment: I'm guessing that your inner joins are filtering out all products. Is there any product that exists in *all* the tables? Because that's what the inner join is filtering for. You might not be able to do this in a single UPDATE.

Comment: Convert it to a SELECT statement and see if any rows are found.

Comment: I have 5000 products in tables and they are in every table. I tested also with separate queries for each table (for eg. `UPDATE lp2_product tabela 
   INNER JOIN temp_update_stany csv ON (tabela.id_product = csv.produkt)
  SET tabela.active = csv.active,tabela.price = csv.price`)

Comment: Then I'd guess that your csv data doesn't have any values that match your `id_product` data.

Comment: One other possibility: if the data has *already* been updated, so the `UPDATE` is effectively a no-op, then the rows affected will be reported as zero.

Comment: This query works good - `SELECT tabela.id_product FROM lp2_product tabela
        INNER JOIN lp2_stock_available stany ON (tabela.id_product = stany.id_product)
        INNER JOIN lp2_product_lang lang ON (tabela.id_product = lang.id_product)
        INNER JOIN temp_update_stany csv ON (tabela.id_product = csv.produkt)`.

Comment: I checked - id_product are in temp_update_stany, lp2_product etc. the same.

Comment: Oh... you have right. Tables are updated. I'm happy :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per comments above, the `UPDATE` reports zero rows affected if there is no net change. So if the tables are already updated with the desired values, the `UPDATE` is a no-op and no rows are "affected."